# React js Issue while setting environment Webpack has been initialised

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am setting the environment for the react js and i am facing the below error.

I am following the 
link -- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.html

Let me correct if i need to make changes

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).

Comment: Link -- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

Comment: when i am using npm start command i am getting the above error..

Comment: Below is the code for webpack-config.js  ---var config = {
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
      path:'/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
module.exports = config;

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't expecting "loaders" to be under module. The configuration looks different according to the docs.
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/

Try:

```
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path:'/',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        }]
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```